# CSRF protection for Angular 16 webapp and Flask API

Tags: javascript, python, angular, flask, csrf

We have a regular Flask REST API (not using Flask-Restful) and our frontend is Angular 15. We want to make sure our webapp is CSRF protected. After some research we figured out that `flask_wtf.csrf` provides CSRF protection, so we did this:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, generate_csrf
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'APP SECRET KEY'
CSRFProtect(app)
....

@app.after_request
def inject_csrf_token(response):
    xsrf_token = generate_csrf()
    response.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrf_token)
    response.set_cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', xsrf_token)
    return response
```

The above code results in the below response headers:

```
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=asdasdas....;Path=/
Set-Cookie: asdasd....; HttpOnly; Path=/
Vary: Origin, Cookie
X-Xsrf-Token: asdasdas....
```

But, no cookies are set.
[image]

My Angular 15 service call looks like this:

```
constructor(_http: HttpClient, _token: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {}

get xsrfToken(): string {
    return this._token.getToken();
}

const headers = {
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            
};

const requestConfig = {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers,
};

return this._http.post<T>(url, data, requestConfig);
```

HttpXsrfTokenExtractor.getToken() always returns null. I am the extracting the **X-XSRF-Token** from the response header using an interceptor and then storing that in a variable and then passing it in the request header for every PUT, POST or DELETE call. I get
`flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF token is missing.` on the server. I am not sure what am I missing. Can someone please guide me? Why is it not setting up the cookie in the browser? I am also importing `HttpClientXsrfModule` in `app.module.ts`

PS: I have only posted the relevant code to keep this question as simple as possible.

Comment: looks like default name for WTF CSRF token in header is "X-CSRFToken"... maybe you need to use that name?